# Delaying while loop doing HttpRequest in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, delay

I'm doing some HTTP header testing to check if a url is alive or not. Im doing this with random generated string urls going through a while loop which calls the HttpRequest function. The problem is that as long as HttpWebRequest is Async the while loop keeps running taking alot of processes checking hell of alot links at the same time. So what i would like to do is ti delay the while loop for either some seconds/milliseconds or simply wait for the HttpWebRequest to only handle like 3 requests at a time. Im just lost here and i dont know how to do so.

My while loop looks like this

```
 String Episode = textBox1.Text;
            String Rand = newInt(16);
            String Url = "http://someurl.com?_" + Episode + "paradisehotel_" + Rand + ".wmv";

            while (checkUrl(Url) == false)
            {
                Rand = newInt(16);
                while (isInList(Rand, list))
                {
                    Rand = newInt(16);
                }

                list.Add(Rand);

                Url = "someurl.com_" + Episode + "paradisehotel_" + Rand + ".wmv";
            }
```

My CheckUrl function looks like this

```
private bool checkUrl(String url)
{

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@url);
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
    try
    {
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
        return true;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }

}
```

I hope someone way more clever than me has a solution.
Thank you mostly
Jonas

Comment: Any reason you're not using the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)?

Comment: I honestly dont know that class. i just need to check if the link exists or returns 403 or anything like that. can the webclient do that?

Comment: the code you posted is single not async though. are you saying you want to use BeginGetResponse()? this method does have an async callback that you could use to increment a counter. then jus check the counter prior to executing the next request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (too much code to copy and paste it all here), which uses an async callback, and increment a static counter inside the callback, after you have loaded the response. Then all you need to do is check the counter isn't over a max value in each iteration of the while loop prior to executing the next request, by using a thread.sleep.